# Android equivalent of top level menu

Tags: android, design-patterns, user-interface

Desktop apps have top level menus (File, Edit, Search, ..., Help).

Web apps have very similar thing, menu tabs (Logo, Questions, Tags, Users, Badges, ...).

However I cannot find equivalent of top level menu in Android framework. Assume that my app has 5 main activities. According to [menu design guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/menu_design.html) options menu should contain actions related to current activity. So how an app should allow users to easily switch to one of five main activities.

It seems that different apps solve the problem in different ways. Some have a tab list at the top of the screen, some at the bottom. Even Google applications aren't consisted in that field. Google Listen has an options menu item called 'Listen Home', however Listen main activity has no that options menu item. Others have two icons in app luncher which start two different activities from one app.

I realize that due to small phone screens Android apps have to be designed in a slightly different way than web or desktop apps. But I have a feeling that the app top level menu topic was omitted in Android framework. And developers are on their own here. Or am I missing something?

Update: this is Google blueprint for a great app

Update2: this [an example app](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/) of these patterns

Update3: [GreenDroid](https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid) library helps a lot implementing these patters in your apps. It seems that dashboard and action bar patterns are becoming quite popular.

[image]

Comment: "Web apps have very similar thing, menu tabs (Logo, Questions, Tags, Users, Badges, ...)." -- you must be on a different Internet than I am. There are few, if any, standards and conventions in Web apps in terms of navigation. "Logo in upper left leading back to the home page" is just about it. I have 11 tabs open with 11 different navigation patterns, and these include major apps (GMail, Remember the Milk, Google Calendar, Seesmic, Google Reader, StackOverflow, GitHub, Evernote, etc.). As with the Web, Android gives you options for establishing navigation patterns, whatever fits your app.

Comment: I am on the Internet Steve Krug writes about in "Don't Make Me Think!" Most apps you have listed have top level menu, just CSS is different.

Comment: It so common that it is already standardized in HTML5, new header, nav, footer tags.

Comment: I think your use of the word 'already' is slightly misplaced - 'at long last' might be better. 20 years of HTML and somebody at long last proposed a standard which has been accepted. :-)

Comment: Is this some kind of a new trend on SO? Discrediting foreigners for slightly misplaced English words? :-)

Comment: @Greg Dan: I'm not sure it is a trend on SO but I assure you it is something I NEVER do. I hadn't visited your profile so wasn't aware that you are from Poland. There's also nothing particularly about your name which would suggest you aren't English. The standard of your written English (in your original question) is also very high. Yes, I was poking fun (hence the smiley) but genuinely assumed you to be English for those reasons and the choice of 'already' in relation to the history of HTML was a strange one. I do apologise if my comment appeared xenophobic and can promise you that I'm not.

Comment: @MisterSquonk No problem. I guess I overreacted a bit after reading Mr 65000 points comment. Fortunately the SO crowd is much wiser than a single individual and directed me to the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at this Google I/O session: http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/android-ui-design-patterns.html

They talk about the design patterns they used for the Twitter application and basically the type of concept you are asking about. Basically, your activity should have a top bar that gives the user specific tasks to do in the view or allows them to switch into another activity.

Google has not implemented anything like this into the actual SDK yet so you're sort of on your own in terms of implementing it but the main concept is given in the presentation. This is the direction that Google would like to see Android shift into though.

Hopefully this helps you out somewhat.

Comment: Excellent video. Dashboard and action bar are exactly what I need. I just noticed that Evernote app also follows that design pattern. Knowing that this is recommended by Google folks, I'll safely go into that direction.

Comment: There's also a blog post that describes the patterns if you prefer text http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/twitter-for-android-closer-look-at.html

Answer (score 1):

The file/edit menus of desktop apps have a very different purpose than the questions/tags etc. tabs at the top of this webpage.

The contents of the file/edit menu should be implemented as in the options menu that appears when you press the menu button.  This is, as you noted, to save space on the smaller screens.

App navigation like the questions/tags etc could be implemented using a [Tab Layout](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html). You are right that apps vary in whether or not the tabs are on the top or bottom, but I don't think thats a huge deal.  In my unscientific look through apps on my phone, the bottom seems to be more common.  However, I think it might depend on your specific implementation which you decide.

A lot of apps don't require any sort of navigation like that, and can get away with just having a path forward or back via the back button.  I think this is preferable for a lot of applications, but won't work in all cases.

I'm not sure what more you would want built into the framework..  It seems like you can accomplish any kind of navigation desired with the above options.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the source of the Google IO app

[ioshed](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/)